# Select conversation between 2 users from Database with SQL

Tags: mysql

A existend private message system shows only the latest message of the conversation but not the complete history between two users. What I want is a simple history where all messages are displayed between to users like whatsapp.

**Database-Structure:**

table users u

```
USER_ID   | username  | ...
```

table privmsgs p

```
MSG_ID  | MSG_TEXT | AUTHOR_ID | MESSAGE_TIME
```

table privmsgs_to t

```
MSG_ID  | AUTHOR_ID (from) | USER_ID (to)
```

What I did:

```
SELECT t.*, p.*, u.*
FROM privmsgs p, phpbb3_privmsgs_to t, phpbb3_users u
WHERE (t.author_id = 37598 AND t.user_id = 74403) 
OR    (t.author_id = 74403 AND t.user_id = 37598)
AND t.msg_id = p.msg_id
AND u.user_id IN (37598, 74403)
ORDER BY p.message_time DESC
```

When I run this query, the SQL server goes into a loop and I have to restart the complete MySQL server. Any Ideas how to get this conversation? Thank you very much.

Comment: First you should read up on the LINK syntax rather than using the old `FROM privmsgs p, phpbb3_privmsgs_to t, phpbb3_users u`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your FROM, i don't how to adapt it.

I think it works :

```
SELECT msg_text
FROM privmsgs
INNER JOIN privmsgs_to ON privmsgs_to.msg_id=privmsgs.msg_id
WHERE (privmsgs_to.author_id = 37598 AND user_id = 74403)
OR (privmsgs_to.author_id = 74403 AND user_id = 37598)
ORDER BY message_time DESC
```

This should display all messages bewteen 37598 and 74403 users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it can help:

```
    SELECT u1.username 'user1', u2.username 'u2', p.msg_text, p.message_time
    FROM privmsgs_to t
    LEFT JOIN privmsgs p ON (t.msg_id = p.msg_id)
    LEFT JOIN users u1 ON (t.author_id = u1.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (t.user_id = u2.user_id)
    WHERE (u1.user_id = 37598 AND u2.user_id = 74403)
       OR (u1.user_id = 74403 AND u2.user_id = 37598)
    ORDER BY p.message_time DESC
```